# Variation of g, $\Vert f \Vert$, being less than variation of $\hat g$ on page 49 of Schechter's Principle of Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, inequality, bounded-variation, total-variation

I am confused by how $V(g) = \Vert f \Vert ≤ V(\hat g),$ with $f$ being a bounded linear functional, come about via (2.48) and (2.49) on page 49 of Schechter's Principle of Functional Analysis.

First the total variation V(g) is defined as

$$V(g) = \sup \sum_{i=1}^n \vert g(t_{i})-g(t_{i-1}) \vert$$

And of course (2.48) and (2.49)

(2.48)
$$\vert \int_{a}^b x(t)dg(t) \vert ≤ \Vert x \Vert V(g) $$
(2.49)
$$V(g) = \Vert f \Vert$$

Based on my understanding, $\hat g$ comes about in order to prove uniqueness of g (see page 48).

First suppose on the contrary $\exists g_1, g_2$ w. bounded variation s.t.
$$f(x) = \int_{a}^b x(t)dg_{i}(t), x \in C[a,b]$$

With $g=g_1-g_2,$ (2.50) comes about
$$0 = \int_{a}^b x(t)dg_{i}(t), x \in C[a,b]$$

And after about 1.5 pages of tip-towing around (the M-beast),$\hat g$ is introduced as a normalized version of g.

And to make my head spinning even faster, at last the conclusion is going to be $V(g) = \Vert f \Vert = V(\hat g)$ by arguing that $V(\hat g) < V(g)$???

I am self-studying (the book is online) and found this section really hard to follow/swallow. Any tips/comments are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing. Post edited and dust off my latex.

Comment: You are unlikely to receive an answer, because one must first find the book and then read it in order to understand what you are talking about. What you have written is unfortunately impossible to follow, because the objects that appear are not introduced in a way that is self-contained.

Comment: Could you clarify which part that appears to be not self-contained? Thx.

Comment: What are the functions $f,g, \hat g$? What is $x(t)$? Your formula for the total variation is incorrect, but its a standard definition so thats fine. When you write $\int x dg$ you mean the Riemann-Stieltjes integral?

Comment: $f$ being a linear bounded functional, $g$ being a function of bounded variation with $g(s) = f(k_{s})$, where $k_{s}(t) = 1^{+}(t)-1^{+}(t-s).$ Formula is corrected, thanks. Yes the whole argument centre around Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Comment: What is g hat? It not defined here.

Comment: By the way, this section is not essential for the further development in the book. It’s just a concrete motivating example, I think.

Comment: During the holiday seasons I have read the whole passage again and it seems the argument is summarized in the following order. Up to (2.49), it is established that each bounded linear functional $f$ on $C[a,b]$ is represented with function $g$ of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ s.t. $$f(x) = \int_{a}^b x(t)dg_{i}(t), x \in C[a,b]$$ and $V(g) = \Vert f \Vert.$ The real trickery is to establish the previous statement with the unique and normalized $g,$ a.k.a. $g^{^}.$

Comment: type* $\hat g.$

Comment: It's a pretty concrete motivation for me, I guess...

Comment: Now Lemma 2.13 is introduced to establish the uniqueness and its subsequent arguments involving $w(t).$ The part that still keeps me up at night is how $\hat g,$ an established normalized function become unique thru. Lemma 2.13. And of course the tour-de-force of Theorem 2.14 follows once $\hat g$ is established as unique, normalized, of bounded variation. This thread now doubles as my own reminder for how this long-line of proof follows. I guess the preface has warned ahead that the proof in this book follows the train of thought of the late Professor rather than the conventional logic.